# Problems with Async function and BitArmory ReCaptcha

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha-v3

I'm using **Google ReCaptcha** and **BitArmory NuGet** package for my contact form. I checked logs on Azure and I see that some people getting an error response from BitArmory ReCaptcha (**siteKey: can not be null??**).

I try multiple ways to store my site key. On the beginning in my common global variables. Next, I created a local string variable in a function and inserted to the captcha function. Very last step it was to hard code my site key string to captcha. In all the cases the same results, some people still getting a response about **siteKey:can not be null???**

Here is my form part of my form:

```
@section head {
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxxxxxx"></script>
}

 <form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/site/comments">
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="captcha"></label>
                       <input id="captcha" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="captcha" value=""/>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
                       <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Email" name="email" placeholder="me@email.com"/>
                       </div>
                   </div>

div class="col-lg-10">
                           <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="SubmitClicked()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send us your feedback!"/>
                       </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function SubmitClicked() {
          $("#submitBtn").attr('disabled', true);
          ExecuteReCaptcha();
        }
function ExecuteReCaptcha() {
            grecaptcha.ready(function() {
              grecaptcha.execute('xxxxxxxx', {action: 'xxxxx'})
                .then(function(token) {
                   // Set `token` in a hidden form input.
                   $("#captcha").val(token);
                   // POST Form
                  postForm();
                });
            });
          }
function postForm() {
  $("#contactForm").submit();
```

And my server-side:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Comments(string email, string captcha, string regarding, string comment)
        {
            var clientIp = Request.UserHostAddress;
            var token = captcha;
            var secret = "xxxxxxxxx";
            var captchaApi = new ReCaptchaService();
            var results = await captchaApi.Verify3Async(token, clientIp, secret);

            if (IsValidEmail(email) && (!results.IsSuccess || results.Score < 0.5 || results.Action != "xxxxxx"))
            {
                ErrorViewModel eVm = new ErrorViewModel
                {
                    message = "\"" + email + "\" is not a valid email address.",
                    bShowBackButton = true
                };
                return View("Error", eVm);
            }
```

Some of the clients are getting the response:

```
System.ArgumentException: The client response must not be null or empty
Parameter name: siteSecret
   at BitArmory.ReCaptcha.ReCaptchaService.<Verify3Async>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at BootstrappingMVC.Controllers.SiteController.<Comments>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Sorry about that. ReCaptcha v5.0 is now released. The correct null/empty parameter name should show up in the exception message now: https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitArmory.ReCaptcha/5.0.0

Comment: @BrianChavez Thank you for update.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your `siteSecret`. There is a bug in BitArmory.Recaptcha code([GitHub](https://github.com/BitArmory/ReCaptcha/blob/73010b9a110c3bd76069970377232cd5eb40dd9f/BitArmory.ReCaptcha/ReCaptchaService.cs#L82-L85)):

```
  public virtual async Task<ReCaptcha3Response> Verify3Async(string clientToken, string remoteIp, string siteSecret, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
     if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(siteSecret) ) throw new ArgumentException("The secret must not be null or empty", nameof(siteSecret));
     if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientToken) ) throw new ArgumentException("The client response must not be null or empty", nameof(siteSecret));
```

Both `if` statements throw `ArgumentException` that blames `siteSecret` even though the message is providing the correct reason. In your case it's the `token` that's empty, not `secret`.

As to why the token can be empty, I think it's because you're not preventing default handling of your button click which submits the form before the `grecaptcha` executes.

Try modifying your `SubmitClicked` function as follows:

```
function SubmitClicked(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#submitBtn").attr('disabled', true);
    ExecuteReCaptcha();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. After debugging I figure out that token is not being set on the front-end. Answer to my problem was e.preventDefault() and using .NET MVC Html.Hidden() to set the reCaptcha value instead of regular HTML input field.